# Gson copys only the 1st 3 elements of the json array

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I am having a problem in json parsing. I am using volley to fetch the data and gson to put the data in a java object. I am not getting any errors for the code, 
but I am receiving all the data through volley but only 3 elements from the array are copied from the json data by gson.

This is the code for fetching the data

```
 public void get_Standing_data(final Context context,String league){

    final Workdone workdone= (Workdone) context;
    final String Url = "http://api.football-data.org/v2/competitions/"+league+"/standings";
    final RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
    final StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            CompetitionStanding data=null;
            Log.d("fetched data", "onResponse: " + response);
            GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
            Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
            data = gson.fromJson(response, CompetitionStanding.class);
            workdone.standing_done(data);
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            workdone.standing_notdone();
            //  Toast.makeText(context, "something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }){
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String>  params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("X-Auth-Token", key);
            params.put("Accept", "application/json");
            return params;
        }
    };


    queue.add(request);


}
```

This is the object

```
 public class CompetitionStanding {

    @SerializedName("filters")
    @Expose
    private Filters filters;
    @SerializedName("competition")
    @Expose
    private Competition competition;
    @SerializedName("season")
    @Expose
    private Season season;
    @SerializedName("standings")
    @Expose
    private List<Standing> standings = null;

    public Filters getFilters() {
        return filters;
    }

    public void setFilters(Filters filters) {
        this.filters = filters;
    }

    public Competition getCompetition() {
        return competition;
    }

    public void setCompetition(Competition competition) {
        this.competition = competition;
    }

    public Season getSeason() {
        return season;
    }

    public void setSeason(Season season) {
        this.season = season;
    }

    public List<Standing> getStandings() {
        return standings;
    }

    public void setStandings(List<Standing> standings) {
        this.standings = standings;
    }

}
```

This is the response from the api

```
  {"filters":{},"competition":{"id":2021,"area":{"id":2072,"name":"England"},"name":"Premier League","code":"PL","plan":"TIER_ONE","lastUpdated":"2018-09-03T22:50:06Z"},"season":{"id":151,"startDate":"2018-08-10","endDate":"2019-05-12","currentMatchday":5},"standings":[{"stage":"REGULAR_SEASON","type":"TOTAL","group":null,"table":[{"position":1,"team":{"id":64,"name":"Liverpool FC","crestUrl":"http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/0/0a/FC_Liverpool.svg"},"playedGames":4,"won":4,"draw":0,"lost":0,"points":12,"goalsFor":9,"goalsAgainst":1,"goalDifference":8},{"position":2,"team":{"id":61,"name":"Chelsea FC","crestUrl":"http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/5/5c/Chelsea_crest.svg"},"playedGames":4,"won":4,"draw":0,"lost":0,"points":12,"goalsFor":10,"goalsAgainst":3,"goalDifference":7},{"position":3,"team":{"id":346,"name":"Watford FC","crestUrl":"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/e/e2/Watford.svg"},"playedGames":4,"won":4,"draw":0,"lost":0,"points":12,"goalsFor":9,"goalsAgainst":3,"goalDifference":6},{"position":4,"team":{"id":65,"name":"Manchester City FC","crestUrl":"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/e/eb/Manchester_City_FC_badge.svg"},"playedGames":4,"won":3,"draw":1,"lost":0,"points":10,"goalsFor":11,"goalsAgainst":3,"goalDifference":8},{"position":5,"team":{"id":73,"name":"Tottenham Hotspur FC","crestUrl":"http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/b/b4/Tottenham_Hotspur.svg"},"playedGames":4,"won":3,"draw":0,"lost":1,"points":9,"goalsFor":9,"goalsAgainst":4,"goalDifference":5},{"position":6,"team":{"id":1044,"name":"AFC Bournemouth","crestUrl":"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/4/41/Afc_bournemouth.svg"},"playedGames":4,"won":2,"draw":1,"lost":1,"points":7,"goalsFor":6,"goalsAgainst":5,"goalDifference":1},{"position":7,"team":{"id":62,"name":"Everton FC","crestUrl":"http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/f/f9/Everton_FC.svg"},"playedGames":4,"won":1,"draw":3,"lost":0,"points":6,"goalsFor":7,"goalsAgainst":6,"goalDifference":1},{"position":8,"team":{"id":338,"name":"Leicester City FC","crestUrl":"http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/6/63/Leicester02.png"},"playedGames":4,"won":2,"draw":0,"lost":2,"points":6,"goalsFor":6,"goalsAgainst":5,"goalDifference":1},{"position":9,"team":{"id":57,"name":"Arsenal FC","crestUrl":"http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/5/53/Arsenal_FC.svg"},"playedGames":4,"won":2,"draw":0,"lost":2,"points":6,"goalsFor":8,"goalsAgainst":8,"goalDifference":0},{"position":10,"team":{"id":66,"name":"Manchester United FC","crestUrl":"http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/d/da/Manchester_United_FC.svg"},"playedGames":4,"won":2,"draw":0,"lost":2,"points":6,"goalsFor":6,"goalsAgainst":7,"goalDifference":-1},{"position":11,"team":{"id":76,"name":"Wolverhampton Wanderers FC","crestUrl":"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/f/fc/Wolverhampton_Wanderers.svg"},"playedGames":4,"won":1,"draw":2,"lost":1,"points":5,"goalsFor":4,"goalsAgainst":5,"goalDifference":-1},{"position":12,"team":{"id":340,"name":"Southampton FC","crestUrl":"http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/c/c9/FC_Southampton.svg"},"playedGames":4,"won":1,"draw":1,"lost":2,"points":4,"goalsFor":4,"goalsAgainst":4,"goalDifference":0},{"position":13,"team":{"id":63,"name":"Fulham FC","crestUrl":"http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/a/a8/Fulham_fc.svg"},"playedGames":4,"won":1,"draw":1,"lost":2,"points":4,"goalsFor":7,"goalsAgainst":9,"goalDifference":-2},{"position":14,"team":{"id":397,"name":"Brighton & Hove Albion FC","crestUrl":"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/f/fd/Brighton_%26_Hove_Albion_logo.svg"},"playedGames":4,"won":1,"draw":1,"lost":2,"points":4,"goalsFor":5,"goalsAgainst":7,"goalDifference":-2},{"position":15,"team":{"id":354,"name":"Crystal Palace FC","crestUrl":"http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/b/bf/Crystal_Palace_F.C._logo_%282013%29.png"},"playedGames":4,"won":1,"draw":0,"lost":3,"points":3,"goalsFor":3,"goalsAgainst":6,"goalDifference":-3},{"position":16,"team":{"id":715,"name":"Cardiff City FC","crestUrl":"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/3/3c/Cardiff_City_crest.svg"},"playedGames":4,"won":0,"draw":2,"lost":2,"points":2,"goalsFor":2,"goalsAgainst":5,"goalDifference":-3},{"position":17,"team":{"id":394,"name":"Huddersfield Town AFC","crestUrl":"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/5/5a/Huddersfield_Town_A.F.C._logo.svg"},"playedGames":4,"won":0,"draw":2,"lost":2,"points":2,"goalsFor":2,"goalsAgainst":10,"goalDifference":-8},{"position":18,"team":{"id":67,"name":"Newcastle United FC","crestUrl":"http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/5/56/Newcastle_United_Logo.svg"},"playedGames":4,"won":0,"draw":1,"lost":3,"points":1,"goalsFor":3,"goalsAgainst":6,"goalDifference":-3},{"position":19,"team":{"id":328,"name":"Burnley FC","crestUrl":"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/0/02/Burnley_FC_badge.png"},"playedGames":4,"won":0,"draw":1,"lost":3,"points":1,"goalsFor":3,"goalsAgainst":9,"goalDifference":-6},{"position":20,"team":{"id":563,"name":"West Ham United FC","crestUrl":"http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/e/e0/West_Ham_United_FC.svg"},"playedGames":4,"won":0,"draw":0,"lost":4,"points":0,"goalsFor":2,"goalsAgainst":10,"goalDifference":-8}]},{"stage":"REGULAR_SEASON","type":"HOME","group":null,"table":[{"position":1,"team":{"id":346,"name":"Watford FC","crestUrl":"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/e/e2/Watford.svg"},"playedGames":3,"won":3,"draw":0,"lost":0,"points":9,"goalsFor":6,"goalsAgainst":2,"goalDifference":4},{"position":2,"team":{"id":65,"name":"Manchester City FC","crestUrl":"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/e/eb/Manchester_City_FC_badge.svg"},"playedGames":2,"won":2,"draw":0,"lost":0,"points":6,"goalsFor":8,"goalsAgainst":2,"goalDifference":6},{"position":3,"team":{"id":64,"name":"Liverpool FC","crestUrl":"http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/0/0a/FC_Liverpool.svg"},"playedGames":2,"won":2,"draw":0,"lost":0,"points":6,"goalsFor":5,"goalsAgainst":0,"goalDifference":5},{"position":4,"team":{"id":61,"name":"Chelsea FC","crestUrl":"http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/5/5c/Chelsea_crest.svg"},"playedGames":2,"won":2,"draw":0,"lost":0,"points":6,"goalsFor":5,"goalsAgainst":2,"goalDifference":3},{"position":5,"team":{"id":1044,"name":"AFC Bournemouth","crestUrl":"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/4/41/Afc_bournemouth.svg"},"playedGames":2,"won":1,"draw":1,"lost":0,"points":4,"goalsFor":4,"goalsAgainst":2,"goalDifference":2},{"position":6,"team":{"id":397,"name":"Brighton & Hove Albion FC","crestUrl":"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/f/fd/Brighton_%26_Hove_Albion_logo.svg"},"playedGames":2,"won":1,"draw":1,"lost":0,"points":4,"goalsFor":5,"goalsAgainst":4,"goalDifference":1},{"position":7,"team":{"id":62,"name":"Everton FC","crestUrl":"http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/f/f9/Everton_FC.svg"},"playedGames":2,"won":1,"draw":1,"lost":0,"points":4,"goalsFor":3,"goalsAgainst":2,"goalDifference":1},{"position":8,"team":{"id":73,"name":"Tottenham Hotspur FC","crestUrl":"http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/b/b4/Tottenham_Hotspur.svg"},"playedGames":1,"won":1,"draw":0,"lost":0,"points":3,"goalsFor":3,"goalsAgainst":1,"goalDifference":2},{"position":9,"team":{"id":338,"name":"Leicester City FC","crestUrl":"http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/6/63/Leicester02.png"},"playedGames":2,"won":1,"draw":0,"lost":1,"points":3,"goalsFor":3,"goalsAgainst":2,"goalDifference":1},{"position":10,"team":{"id":63,"name":"Fulham FC","crestUrl":"http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/a/a8/Fulham_fc.svg"},"playedGames":2,"won":1,"draw":0,"lost":1,"points":3,"goalsFor":4,"goalsAgainst":4,"goalDifference":0},{"position":11,"team":{"id":57,"name":"Arsenal FC","crestUrl":"http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/5/53/Arsenal_FC.svg"},"playedGames":2,"won":1,"draw":0,"lost":1,"points":3,"goalsFor":3,"goalsAgainst":3,"goalDifference":0},{"position":12,"team":{"id":66,"name":"Manchester United FC","crestUrl":"http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/d/da/Manchester_United_FC.svg"},"playedGames":2,"won":1,"draw":0,"lost":1,"points":3,"goalsFor":2,"goalsAgainst":4,"goalDifference":-2},{"position":13,"team":{"id":76,"name":"Wolverhampton Wanderers FC","crestUrl":"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/f/fc/Wolverhampton_Wanderers.svg"},"playedGames":2,"won":0,"draw":2,"lost":0,"points":2,"goalsFor":3,"goalsAgainst":3,"goalDifference":0},{"position":14,"team":{"id":715,"name":"Cardiff City FC","crestUrl":"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/3/3c/Cardiff_City_crest.svg"},"playedGames":2,"won":0,"draw":1,"lost":1,"points":1,"goalsFor":2,"goalsAgainst":3,"goalDifference":-1},{"position":15,"team":{"id":340,"name":"Southampton FC","crestUrl":"http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/c/c9/FC_Southampton.svg"},"playedGames":2,"won":0,"draw":1,"lost":1,"points":1,"goalsFor":1,"goalsAgainst":2,"goalDifference":-1},{"position":16,"team":{"id":394,"name":"Huddersfield Town AFC","crestUrl":"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/5/5a/Huddersfield_Town_A.F.C._logo.svg"},"playedGames":2,"won":0,"draw":1,"lost":1,"points":1,"goalsFor":0,"goalsAgainst":3,"goalDifference":-3},{"position":17,"team":{"id":67,"name":"Newcastle United FC","crestUrl":"http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/5/56/Newcastle_United_Logo.svg"},"playedGames":2,"won":0,"draw":0,"lost":2,"points":0,"goalsFor":2,"goalsAgainst":4,"goalDifference":-2},{"position":18,"team":{"id":563,"name":"West Ham United FC","crestUrl":"http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/e/e0/West_Ham_United_FC.svg"},"playedGames":2,"won":0,"draw":0,"lost":2,"points":0,"goalsFor":1,"goalsAgainst":3,"goalDifference":-2},{"position":19,"team":{"id":328,"name":"Burnley FC","crestUrl":"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/0/02/Burnley_FC_badge.png"},"playedGames":2,"won":0,"draw":0,"lost":2,"points":0,"goalsFor":1,"goalsAgainst":5,"goalDifference":-4},{"position":20,"team":{"id":354,"name":"Crystal Palace FC","crestUrl":"http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/b/bf/Crystal_Palace_F.C._logo_%282013%29.png"},"playedGames":2,"won":0,"draw":0,"lost":2,"points":0,"goalsFor":0,"goalsAgainst":4,"goalDifference":-4}]},{"stage":"REGULAR_SEASON","type":"AWAY","group":null,"table":[{"position":1,"team":{"id":61,"name":"Chelsea FC","crestUrl":"http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/5/5c/Chelsea_crest.svg"},"playedGames":2,"won":2,"draw":0,"lost":0,"points":6,"goalsFor":5,"goalsAgainst":1,"goalDifference":4},{"position":2,"team":{"id":73,"name":"Tottenham Hotspur FC","crestUrl":"http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/b/b4/Tottenham_Hotspur.svg"},"playedGames":3,"won":2,"draw":0,"lost":1,"points":6,"goalsFor":6,"goalsAgainst":3,"goalDifference":3},{"position":3,"team":{"id":64,"name":"Liverpool FC","crestUrl":"http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/0/0a/FC_Liverpool.svg"},"playedGames":2,"won":2,"draw":0,"lost":0,"points":6,"goalsFor":4,"goalsAgainst":1,"goalDifference":3},{"position":4,"team":{"id":65,"name":"Manchester City FC","crestUrl":"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/e/eb/Manchester_City_FC_badge.svg"},"playedGames":2,"won":1,"draw":1,"lost":0,"points":4,"goalsFor":3,"goalsAgainst":1,"goalDifference":2},{"position":5,"team":{"id":346,"name":"Watford FC","crestUrl":"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/e/e2/Watford.svg"},"playedGames":1,"won":1,"draw":0,"lost":0,"points":3,"goalsFor":3,"goalsAgainst":1,"goalDifference":2},{"position":6,"team":{"id":66,"name":"Manchester United FC","crestUrl":"http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/d/da/Manchester_United_FC.svg"},"playedGames":2,"won":1,"draw":0,"lost":1,"points":3,"goalsFor":4,"goalsAgainst":3,"goalDifference":1},{"position":7,"team":{"id":340,"name":"Southampton FC","crestUrl":"http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/c/c9/FC_Southampton.svg"},"playedGames":2,"won":1,"draw":0,"lost":1,"points":3,"goalsFor":3,"goalsAgainst":2,"goalDifference":1},{"position":8,"team":{"id":354,"name":"Crystal Palace FC","crestUrl":"http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/b/bf/Crystal_Palace_F.C._logo_%282013%29.png"},"playedGames":2,"won":1,"draw":0,"lost":1,"points":3,"goalsFor":3,"goalsAgainst":2,"goalDifference":1},{"position":9,"team":{"id":57,"name":"Arsenal FC","crestUrl":"http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/5/53/Arsenal_FC.svg"},"playedGames":2,"won":1,"draw":0,"lost":1,"points":3,"goalsFor":5,"goalsAgainst":5,"goalDifference":0},{"position":10,"team":{"id":338,"name":"Leicester City FC","crestUrl":"http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/6/63/Leicester02.png"},"playedGames":2,"won":1,"draw":0,"lost":1,"points":3,"goalsFor":3,"goalsAgainst":3,"goalDifference":0},{"position":11,"team":{"id":1044,"name":"AFC Bournemouth","crestUrl":"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/4/41/Afc_bournemouth.svg"},"playedGames":2,"won":1,"draw":0,"lost":1,"points":3,"goalsFor":2,"goalsAgainst":3,"goalDifference":-1},{"position":12,"team":{"id":76,"name":"Wolverhampton Wanderers FC","crestUrl":"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/f/fc/Wolverhampton_Wanderers.svg"},"playedGames":2,"won":1,"draw":0,"lost":1,"points":3,"goalsFor":1,"goalsAgainst":2,"goalDifference":-1},{"position":13,"team":{"id":62,"name":"Everton FC","crestUrl":"http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/f/f9/Everton_FC.svg"},"playedGames":2,"won":0,"draw":2,"lost":0,"points":2,"goalsFor":4,"goalsAgainst":4,"goalDifference":0},{"position":14,"team":{"id":67,"name":"Newcastle United FC","crestUrl":"http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/5/56/Newcastle_United_Logo.svg"},"playedGames":2,"won":0,"draw":1,"lost":1,"points":1,"goalsFor":1,"goalsAgainst":2,"goalDifference":-1},{"position":15,"team":{"id":63,"name":"Fulham FC","crestUrl":"http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/a/a8/Fulham_fc.svg"},"playedGames":2,"won":0,"draw":1,"lost":1,"points":1,"goalsFor":3,"goalsAgainst":5,"goalDifference":-2},{"position":16,"team":{"id":328,"name":"Burnley FC","crestUrl":"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/0/02/Burnley_FC_badge.png"},"playedGames":2,"won":0,"draw":1,"lost":1,"points":1,"goalsFor":2,"goalsAgainst":4,"goalDifference":-2},{"position":17,"team":{"id":715,"name":"Cardiff City FC","crestUrl":"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/3/3c/Cardiff_City_crest.svg"},"playedGames":2,"won":0,"draw":1,"lost":1,"points":1,"goalsFor":0,"goalsAgainst":2,"goalDifference":-2},{"position":18,"team":{"id":394,"name":"Huddersfield Town AFC","crestUrl":"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/5/5a/Huddersfield_Town_A.F.C._logo.svg"},"playedGames":2,"won":0,"draw":1,"lost":1,"points":1,"goalsFor":2,"goalsAgainst":7,"goalDifference":-5},{"position":19,"team":{"id":397,"name":"Brighton & Hove Albion FC","crestUrl":"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/f/fd/Brighton_%26_Hove_Albion_logo.svg"},"playedGames":2,"won":0,"draw":0,"lost":2,"points":0,"goalsFor":0,"goalsAgainst":3,"goalDifference":-3},{"position":20,"team":{"id":563,"name":"West Ham United FC","crestUrl":"http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/e/e0/West_Ham_United_FC.svg"},"playedGames":2,"won":0,"draw":0,"lost":2,"points":0,"goalsFor":1,"goalsAgainst":7,"goalDifference":-6}]}]}
```

but only 3 elements are copied from this json
am I doing anything wrong?
any help will be appreciated

Comment: if you check the standings array, you will see that **it has exactly 3 elements**.

Comment: which one is missing?